# set visual studio 2008 compiler for c not c++

Tags: c++, c, compiler-construction

I have installed visual studio 2008 and i want to create some simple applications using C language. I do this by creating c++ console applications but i want the compiler to work for C not C++. Any way to accomplish this or i need another compiler if i want to deal with C?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Use .c file extension instead of .cpp**, those files will be compiled as C-only code by default in a C/C++ Visual Studio project.

Answer (score 4):

Just create files ending with .c instead of .cpp - MSVC will run the C compiler on them automatically. Note that it also allows you to intermix C and C++ freely (in different files, of course), as long as you stick to the rules (`extern "C"`, etc.)

Answer (score 4):

Try using `/TP` `/TC` compiler flags, you can find them in compiler group of project settings. Flags are documented here: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/032xwy55(VS.80).aspx).